# How to create a range for summarized store revenue in Pivot tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a data set that looks something like below:

```
Store   Revenue
1       50
1       100
1       200
1       1001
2       75
2       900
2       100
2       8000
2       2000
3       300
3       300
4       1000
4       200
```

I would like to summarize (total) revenue for each store, which can be done with a pivot table - Store in Rows and Sum of Revenue in values.
Now, I would like to see which stores and their total sum are within a revenue range.
for example - in 0-499 range, none of the stores should show up, 500-999 should have store 3, 1000-1499 should have 1 and 4 and so on

I tried to group by revenue by adding revenue to Columns in pivot table and configuring grouping - starting at 0, ending at 8000, by 500.

in that case, the grouping does not account total sum, but individual sums
for example, 0-499 should not have any stores, but stores 1, 2, 3, 4  show up because there are individual store rows with values < 499 (see output below).

Incorrect output
    Sum of Revenue  Column Labels
    Row Labels  0-499   500-999  1000-1499  2000-2499   7500-8000
    1           350     1001
    2           175     900                 2000        8000
    3           600
    4           200     1000

Desired output
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

1, add the total column to sum the revenue and group by store.

Cell C2 formula:

```
=IF(A2=A1,"",SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B))
```

[image]

2, Add the range column based on the store total revenue.

Cell D2 formula:

```
= IF(C2 <> " ", IF(AND(C2<=499,C2>=0), "0-499",
   IF(AND(C2<=999,C2>=500),"500-999",
     IF(AND(C2<=1499,C2>=1000),"1000-1499",
       IF(AND(C2<=2499,C2>=2000), "2000-2499",
         IF(AND(C2<=8000,C2>=7500), "7500-8000", 
           IF(AND(C2<=11499,C2>=11000), "11000-11499", " ")))))), " ")
```

[image]

3, Since you still need those ranges which may not have any revenue, we need to create every range for each store **manually**.

[image]

4, Insert the Pivot Table.

The same PivotTable Fields arrangement:

[image]

---

Final Result:

[image]

---

**Original Answer:**

Three Step:

1, Create your range column by using below formula:

```
=IF(AND(B2<=499,B2>=0), "0-499", 
   IF(AND(B2<=999,B2>=500),"500-999",
     IF(AND(B2<=1499,B2>=1000),"1000-1499",
       IF(AND(B2<=2499,B2>=2000), "2000-2499",
         IF(AND(B2<=8000,B2>=7500), "7500-8000","0")))))
```

Result is below:

[image]

2, Insert the Pivot Table and put the columns into the correct fields:

[image]

[image]

3, Hide the [Grand total]

[image]

---

***Final Result:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question. I think the output that you have shown is the one I can get with regular pivot table. I don't want range for individual rows for a store, but range for total revenue sum for the store. e.g. store 1 with total revenue of 1351 should be within the range 1000-1499 instead of 0-499 and 1000-1499. same for others. only total sum should be in the range. I hope it make sense. i have added desired output in my question above. thank you again for all the help.

Comment: @user2593173, what is your logic of these ranges? You want to force to set the range like that?

Comment: Thank you again for taking time to answer my question. re:logic of ranges - this is just a sample data. the ranges will depend on what kind of data I get every month back from the stores. this is to help us identify which stores fall in a given range of revenue. therefore, the ranges should be flexible as well. Right now the solution you have provided is kind of hardcoded. the ranges should be flexible and i was hoping that pivot table should have a way to group the total field

Comment: @user2593173, Let's start here. Why will the first column be 0-499? Why not 0-498? You need to create the sample data which makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for replying! that's the point. the sample range can be anything. I just gave an example of 0-499, it can be 0-498 or 0-1000 depending on what kind of data I get back every month. the ranges should be flexible not hard coded but the output should be on total and not on individual

Comment: @user2593173, Now I only know you want it dynamically. But you still do not answer the question. What is the logic of ranges? You need to tell us the logic otherwise we cannot understand.

Comment: @user2593173 For example, this month you got some sample data. Store1: 100, 500, 1000. So for this month, what will the column ranges look like?